# Regular expression to match uri segment in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm working on a JavaScript router engine for a client-side MVC app... something like Backbone or Spine is involved.

My router needs to match URI segments that optionally include resource titles and optionally include request formats.

I'm looking to capture the resource `:id`, optional `:name` segment and optional `:format` segment, such that:

```
/123              => id:'123', name: undefined, format: undefined
/123-my-name      => id:'123', name:'my-name',  format: undefined
/123.html         => id:'123', name: undefined, format:'html'
/123-my-name.html => id:'123', name:'my-name',  format:'html'
```

**EDIT:** There are other routes that will match nested paths, so this expression should not match `/123-my-name/edit` or `/123-my-name/edit.html`

I can easily match the optional `:name` or `:format` segments when they are not both present, but I'm having trouble distinguishing the `:name` from the `:format` when both are present.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please post the expression you have so far.

Comment: This is what I have, but it does not work as expected:
`/^\/(\d+)(?:-(.*))?(?:\.(html))?$/`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
> re = /\/(\w+)(?:-(\w[-\w]+))?(?:\.(html))?/
/\/(\w+)(?:-(\w[-\w]+))?(?:\.(html))?/
> "/123".match(re)
["/123", "123", undefined, undefined]
> "/123-my-name".match(re)
["/123-my-name", "123", "my-name", undefined]
> "/123.html".match(re)
["/123.html", "123", undefined, "html"]
> "/123-my-name.html".match(re)
["/123-my-name.html", "123", "my-name", "html"]
```

then,

```
 m = url.match(re)
 id = m[1]
 name = m[2] || default
 format = m[3] || default
```

A more specific option (id = only digits, anchored):

```
> re = /^\/(\d+)(?:-(\w[-\w]+))?(?:\.(html))?$/
/^\/(\d+)(?:-(\w[-\w]+))?(?:\.(html))?$/
> "/123-my-route/edit.html".match(re)
null
```

Comment: This works except when a nested path is tested, such as `/123-my-route/edit.html`. Any suggestions on that? The nested path should result in no match.

Comment: The more specific, anchored option does what I am looking for, thank you!